# When does a PM create a RAID log

Tags: risk-management

Got a few questions on RAID (Risks, Assumptions, Issues, Dependencies) and RISK registers.

1. In what phase of the project does a PM create a RAID log?
2. I am assuming it is during the planning phase. is it correct?
3. Does a RAID log a way of RISK management?
4. Is Risk Register different than RAID?

Answer (score 1):

Before the project is even chosen.  After all, the contents are part of the project business case.  Without it, your case is not credible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David Espina. Before the project is on-boarded this should be initiated. If it's an internal project or an external project, RAIDs should be evaluated for relevant financial impacts on your project.

Ultimately whether it's time or quality of the deliverables, they will have a negative financial impact if you don't evaluate them before accepting the project. Once a project is started, the risk and issue registers become live documents and will be updated alongside the current status of the project.

Some risks identified will becomes issues and some will not. More effort should be given to Risks and Issues before and at the planning stage of the project, continuous effort should be made to maintain them in an live/active manner throughout the project.